# sscanf format string explicit matching of %d

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following c code

```
if (sscanf(input, "s %d\n", &value) == 1){}
```

Where it is suppose to parse the following

```
s -inf
....
s 0
s 1
s 2
....
s inf
```

but not such things as

```
s 5junkjunkjunk
```

Because it shouldn't match as there is something in between `%d` and the `\n`. Yet it does work even though it doesn't fit the format string.

Comment: You do not do pattern matching with `sscant()`. Instead, it starts at the beginning, and consumes as many bytes as possible per format specifier/format byte. It cannot unread more than one byte, so it does not try. Please read the spec for details. [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @Deduplicator  I suspect some sneaky goings on sometimes concerning "It cannot unread more than one byte" is not always true.  Tried `scanf("%d", &i); scanf("%c", &ch);` with input like "-123x" and `ch` got `'x'` as expected. Tried "-+123x" and got `'-'` as unexpected.  How does the first `scanf("%d", &i)` put back `'-'` and `'+'`?  (gcc Eclipse Kepler).   Suppose I should post this question.

Comment: @chux: I think that's a violation of the standard. Also, it's a good idea to check it before submitting a bug report **for the library**, not for gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (one of the) reasons why one should never use `*scanf`: it's ridiculously difficult to get it to handle malformed input robustly.

The correct way to parse something like this is: use `fgets` (or `getline` if you have it) to read an entire line, manually check for and skip over the leading `"s "`, then use `strtod` to parse the number, then check whether `strtod` set `*endp` to point to a newline.

If the syntax is even a *little* more complicated than what you have it may be time to reach for `lex` and `yacc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [docs for `scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), you'll find that every appearance of a whitespace character in the format string matches *any number of* whitespace characters (including zero) in the input.  `sscanf()` can't be forced to match an entire string -- it "succeeds" if it matches everything in the format string, even if this leaves other characters (`junkjunkjunk`) unconsumed.

Comment: So it stops write when it hits a match instead of checking to see if it should continue on?

Comment: @Zimm3r: No, it stops when it hits a failure to match, and returns how many things it has matched and stored so far.

Comment: @Zimm3r: Well, I don't know what you mean by "should" here.  `sscanf()` "should" not continue on, because that's what the documentation for the function says it will do...

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer

`inf` is nicely read as a floating point.

Agree `scanf()` is cumbersome, but `sscanf()` is versatile.

Note: `"%n"` reports the number of `char` scanned and does not contribute to `sscanf()` result.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input) == NULL) EOForIOerror();
int n;
double x;
if (sscanf("s %lf %n", &x, &n) != 1 || buf[n]) ScanFailure();
// if needed
if (!isinf(x) && round(x) != x) NumberIsNotInfinityNorWholeNumber(); 
// x is good to go
```

Details:

If no legit number is found, `sscanf()` does not return 1 and `ScanFailure()` is called.

Else is a legit number is found, `" %n"` scans any number 0 or more trailing white-spaces such as `'\n'`.  Then it sets the offset of the scan in `n`.  This location will be the first non-white-space after the number.   If it is not `'\0'` then `ScanFailure()` is called.